# dbt build not liste as a possible option

Tags: dbt

We're starting to use DBT at work - it was setup in the past but we're getting back to it, so we don't have a lot of knowledge.

I'm trying to run my models - 'dbt run' works fine but when I try to use 'dbt build' I get the following error:

```
usage: dbt [-h] [--version] [-r RECORD_TIMING_INFO] [-d] [--log-format {text,json,default}] [--no-write-json] [--use-colors | --no-use-colors] [-S] [--warn-error] [--partial-parse | --no-partial-parse]
           {docs,source,init,clean,debug,deps,list,ls,snapshot,rpc,run,compile,parse,test,seed,run-operation} ...
dbt: error: invalid choice: 'build' (choose from 'docs', 'source', 'init', 'clean', 'debug', 'deps', 'list', 'ls', 'snapshot', 'rpc', 'run', 'compile', 'parse', 'test', 'seed', 'run-operation')
```

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: What version of DBT are you running? `dbt build` was added in version 0.21 (https://github.com/dbt-labs/dbt-core/releases/tag/v0.21.0). That was awhile ago, but since you mentioned the project hasn't been touched in a long time, I'm assuming you haven't upgraded to a newer version yet.